# Share certain columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Forms that gets filled. This obviously goes into Google Sheets. I want a summary of this information to be publicly viewed. Kind of like the summary page in sheets but I want only certain columns from the spreadsheets to be in the summary.

Or if only certain columns can be visible publicly and not editable. Only fully visible and editable by the two administrators (myself included).

Which ever way it gets done, I want the summary page to be live to whatever gets edited in sheets by the admins.

Comment: So say, if the form would be a poll, you want to make visible only the results, right?

Comment: Yes kind of.
It's a beta form. I want 3 columns to be visible to the public. B,C,D. 
Now the information in C gets edited making it to reorganize the whole sheet, so I would want the results to shuffle for the 3 showing columns as well.
 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* publish a part of the document. You have to publish the whole thing. But you *can* get a publish url that will show a part of the document, exactly like you want.

Once you Choose to publish the document, and click that "Start Publishing" button, you get this option -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I was able to publish it as D1:E99
Question is though how would I get column B as well as the current D/E without column C?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be possible. If I find something, will update. In the meantime, you could try moving the not-to-publish columns to the left or right of other columns, if possible.

Comment: Another option would be create a 2nd sheet. have the certain columns from sheet1 that I want to share update to sheet2. then publish all of sheet2. Is that possible?

Comment: Then you'll have to keep syncing the sheets. I think that would be another headache. Isn't that right?

Comment: if you have to manually sync the 2 sheets.. yes. if there is something that made it autosync on change... then no

Comment: @Bibhas your example works great, but when I try to publish as 'HTML to embed in a page' it produces a html link which included the whole form. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can sync a portion of the 1st sheet on 2nd sheet automatically with this formula:
="[1st tab]!A1:C1000"
This will, for example, sync first 1000 rows of columns A-C. Then, publish the 2nd sheet.